# How to Manage HTML Element Compression with CSS

Tags: html, css

When the web page is compressed in the X axis, I want main elements of the page to handle the compression correctly.

I'm not very well versed with CSS so i have tried a variety of solutions but none have really worked, they mostly end up with the button ending up on the next line which is not what I want.

```html
<div id="ComposerContainer">
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="messageTextBox" name="messageTextBox" placeholder="Type your message..." autocomplete="off">
        <button id="sendMessageButton" name="sendMessageButton" type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The main one is a  containing a text box and a submit button. When the page is compressed I want the submit button to remain a constant size and the text box to fill the remaining space up until it reaches a minimum size. Hopefully the diagram below helps illustrate this.

[image: Desired Outcome]

Comment: Sorry, this is my first StackOverflow question. Here is the diagram I referenced: https://i.imgur.com/PZTjMNT.jpg

Comment: Sounds like you need `display:flex` - give the button `flex: 0 0 100px;` and the input `flex: 1 0 0;`. Make sure you use media queries to ensure that if the window gets too small, the layout changes to something that fits better.

Comment: Unrelated side-note, `<form method="POST" action="">` is better than using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. An empty `action` will post back to the current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer mentions, you can use `flex` or use `calc` for the width.

```css
input {
  width: calc(100% - 220px);
}

button {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ComposerContainer">
  <form method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="messageTextBox" name="messageTextBox" placeholder="Type your message..." autocomplete="off">
    <button id="sendMessageButton" name="sendMessageButton" type="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/g1hcL5yt/2/

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. Really simple too.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox will do what you want here.

```css
#flexible-form-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
#flexible-form-wrapper input {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="ComposerContainer">
    <form method="POST" id="flexible-form-wrapper">
        <input type="text" id="messageTextBox" name="messageTextBox" placeholder="Type your message..." autocomplete="off">
        <button id="sendMessageButton" name="sendMessageButton" type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```